# "Best regards" vs. "Best Regards"

Tags: capitalization, email, valediction

I have been told that I should use "Best regards" in emails. However, I also see many native English speakers using "Best Regards". I'm confused which is correct.

Comment: When I was learning English I was told that only the first word is capitalized, the rule @godel9 mentioned. However, on Gmail, the autocomplete always shows "Best Regards", never "Best regards". And guido mentioned in one exam the correct answer was "Best Regards" (capitalized). So I'm confused too.

Comment: When I was taught formal letter writing (in the 1970s and 1980s in England) this form was not permitted (or even mentioned). I would need to be convinced there was a "correct" form.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The rule for formal letters is that only the first word should be capitalized (i.e. "Best regards"). Emails are less formal, so some of the rules are relaxed. That's why you're seeing variants from other native English speakers. It would never be wrong, however, to continue using "Best regards" for emails.

Best regards,
godel9

Comment: I am a native English (American) speaker and I did not know this. Can you provide a link that I and other could refer to?

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 A few references...
1) http://emilypost.com/advice/effective-business-letters/
2) http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/01/with_best_wishe.html
3) http://www.upwritepress.com/BlogRetrieve.aspx?BlogID=2395&PostID=82141

Answer (score 1):

I am studying English on the official British Council website. In one of the practice exercises my answer was marked wrong when I used "Best regards" and have been corrected to "Best Regards".

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely use "Best regards" and not Best Regards. However, it is not that emails are less formal or natives are always right.